# First Order Logic to CNF for Knowledge Base

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, artificial-intelligence, conjunctive-normal-form

I am doing some Homework for an Artificial Intelligence Course, we are covering some First Order Logic and Conjuctive Normal Form.

Here are the questions that I have to answer that I am having trouble with

> Q10. [20] Suppose that the sentence A in Q9 is changed to:
>
> A1.    Some great chefs are French.
>
> 1) [6] Write it in the FOL sentence.
>
> a. Existential(x): GC(x) and F(x)
>
> 2) [6] Convert 1) to the the definite clause in CNF, suitable for Knowledge_Base through Skolemization, etc. if necessary.
>
> a. Existential(x): GC(x) and F(x)
>
> b. ¬ (Existential(x): GC(x) and F(x))
>
> c. Universal(x): ¬GC(x) or ¬F(x)
>
> d. Universal(x): GC(x) therefore ¬F(x)
>
> 3) [8] Prove how the same query can be answered (or not).  Justify your answer step by step.

So my question here is, I feel like I am doing the conversion from FOL here to CNF wrong unless you can actually have a negative predicate as a conclusion for CNF for the knowledge base. How would I go about changing this to make it work?

And then I have no idea how to approach #3 to answer the question.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean Conjunctive Normal Form?

Comment: Yes that is what i mean

Answer (score 0):

Your symbolization of 'some great chefs are French' is wrong. That should simply be:

$\exists x (GC(x) \land F(x))$

After negation:

$\neg \exists x (GC(x) \land F(x))$

You get:

$\forall x \neg (GC(x) \land F(x))$

And thus:

$\forall x (\neg GC(x) \lor \neg F(x))$

Comment: Oh lol duh, how is the CNF conversion though?

Comment: Thought for CNF conversion for a knowledge base that it has to be in the form of an implication?

Comment: @Felauras I am not sure what method you are being taught ... if you could speel that out in your post I can provide a more meaningful answer.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I was mistaken and was wrong. I misunderstood the lectures and realized that when I looked back at the lecture notes after you said this.

Answer (score 0):

> Q10. [20] Suppose that the sentence A in Q9 is changed to:
>
> A1. Some great chefs are French.
>
> 1) [6] Write it in the FOL sentence.
>
> a. Existential(x) Universal(y): GC(y) and F(x)

That says: "Everything is a great chef, and something is French."

You want to claim that there is a thing that is a great chef, and this *same* thing is also French.   So you must  use the same token for it.

```
Existential(x): GC(x) and F(x)
```

$$\exists x:(\operatorname{GC}(x)\land \operatorname{F}(x))$$

Comment: So that is changed, what about the CNF conversion?